# Block will not shown if removed somewhere else

Tags: cache, full-page-cache, block-cache

I'm facing this problem even before CE 1.9.2

1. In footer, I create a global custom block with `page/html_wrapper` type like below

```
<default>
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.wrapper" as="bottomWrapper">
        ...
    ...
...
```

2. In some specific pages, such as Shopping Cart, Checkout Onepage,... I don't want to show this custom block, then I remove it by

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
    <remove name="bottom.wrapper"/>
    ...
...
```

or by

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
    <reference name="footer">
        <remove name="bottom.wrapper"/>
        ...
    ...
...
```

or by

```
<checkout_cart_index translate="label">
    <reference name="footer">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>bottomWrapper</name></action>
        ...
    ...
...
```

3. Prolem is, if the first visit page that generates the cache is a global page (such as home page), `footer` will be cached, included `bottom.wrapper` block, then all the above specific pages show `bottom.wrapper` as well. If the first visit page that generates the cache is one of above specific pages, `footer` will be cached without `bottom.wrapper` block, then all other pages won't see `bottom.wrapper` anymore.

Disabling `BLOCK_HTML` cache is a temporary solution. I don't want to hide `bottom.wrapper` block by css.

How to deal with it? How to make `bottom.wrapper` showing properly as desire?

**UPDATE:**

*Because this question has marked duplicate, so I cannot give an answer for my own solution:*

My `bottom.wrapper` is placed in bottom of the pages, doesn't mean it must be included in footer. 
Instead of including in the footer, I create a new child block of the `root`

```
<default>
    <reference name="root">
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.wrapper" as="bottomWrapper">
        ...
    ...
...
```

Then in the page template, such as `1column.phtml`, `2columns-left.phtml`,... I insert before `footer`:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bottomWrapper') ?>
```

By now, `bottomWraper` is cached by its own key, not attached to the `footer` anymore. 
Other step (removing, getting,..) is just like before.

Comment: This question marked duplicate so I cannot give an answer of my own solution. Prolem is I have completely wrong approached at the first place.
I should create a new child block of root instead of altering the footer.

Answer (score 4):

Honestly, I didn't face such "tricky" situations before.. So cannot give you 100% guarantee on below code. I can see two solutions for this.

### 1. Forcefully Make `bottom.wrapper` Never Cached

This is the easiest solution that came into my mind. ie we need to tell Magento that, I don't want to cache this particular block. For this you can try..

```
<default>
    <reference name="footer">
        <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="bottom.wrapper" as="bottomWrapper">
            <action method="setCacheLifeTime"></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
 </default>
```

Setting `cache_life_time` to `NULL` forcefully turn off cache for this particular block.

### 2. Remove The Block Using an Observer

If you want to preserve the cacheing of your custom block and still need to remove your block from specific pages, you need to create a module and observe to the event `controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after` and then remove the block from the layout.

File : `app\code\local\Rkt\BlockRemover\etc\config.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Rkt_BlockRemover>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Rkt_BlockRemover>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <rkt_blockremover>
                <class>Rkt_BlockRemover_Model</class>
            </rkt_blockremover>
        </models>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
                <observers>
                    <remove_cached_blocks>
                        <class>rkt_blockremover/observer</class>
                        <method>removeCacheBlocks</method>
                    </remove_cached_blocks>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after>
        </events>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

File : `app\code\local\Rkt\BlockRemover\Model\Observer.php`

```
<?php
class Rkt_BlockRemover_Model_Observer
{
    public function removeCacheBlocks(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $layout = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout();
        $action = $observer->getEvent()->getAction();

        //make sure block is removing from specific pages that we required
        if ($action->getFullActionName() == 'checkout_cart_index') {
            $layout->unsetBlock('bottom.wrapper');
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Code checks whether the page requested is *checkout_cart_index* page and if yes, it will simply remove `bottom.wrapper` block from the layout.

---

***Note 1*** : I didn't test this code. But I am sure it is close what you need.

***Note 2*** : In either, FLUSHING CACHE before testing is an essential step.

Comment: This question marked duplicate so I cannot give an answer of my own solution. Prolem is I have completely wrong approached at the first place.
I should create a new child block of root instead of altering the footer. Thank you for your answer, it provides some good knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because footer block is cached based on some cache keys.

To have different footer on different page, you need to modify the cache key info for footer block.

Check this out:

```
// Mage_Page_Block_Html_Footer

/**
 * Get cache key informative items
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getCacheKeyInfo()
{
    return array(
        'PAGE_FOOTER',
        Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
        (int)Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure(),
        Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName(),
        Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('template'),
        Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()
    );
}
```

What modification to do in here depends on your need. The easiest solution that came across my mind is to use controller's full action name:

```
public function getCacheKeyInfo()
{
    $info   = parent::getCacheKeyInfo();
    $action = Mage::app()->getFrontController()->getAction();
    if ($action) {
        $info[] = $action->getFullActionName();
    }
    return $info;
}
```

PS: It's untested!

Comment: This question marked duplicate so I cannot give an answer of my own solution. Prolem is I have completely wrong approached at the first place.
I should create a new child block of root instead of alter the footer. Thank you for your answer. It's useful for me someday.